# SSMS SSIS reports

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to reuse reports that is built in SSMS in other applications? Previously it was possible to get rdlc files, but in latest version it does not seem to be possible.

I would love to use "All Executions" report (SQL Server 2014).

Comment: I wasn't aware you could even extract the 2012 version. I find the [SSIS Reporting Pack](http://ssisreportingpack.codeplex.com) to be a better solution as it is